# Marquee on chrome didn't start immediately and disappear suddenly

Tags: html, google-chrome, marquee

I have a big problem with Marquee on chrome.

you can see its behavior here : www.alsafhanews.com

and here is my code

```
<div class="row navbar-fixed-top" id="top-row">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="padding-left: 0px !important;font-size:18px;">
    <strong style="color:#FFF;padding-top:7px; display: block;text-align: left;">أحدث الأخبار:</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="option-nav-col">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">نص جديد مضاف ضمن آخر الأخبار في الموقع <span style="color:#000;font-weight:bold"> :: الصفحة الاخبارية :: </span> </span>
  </marquee>
  </div>      
</div>
```

any one has a new Idea what is going here 
:(

Comment: a "new" idea ? Don't use marquee anymore, 20th century is over...

Comment: I have tried to use 21th century by using Jquery simple Marquee but I got the same result :(

Comment: Then please post this code. As you can read in [tag's info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/marquee/info),  `<marquee>` never has been part of HTML standards.